# converting datatable object to int

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion, int

I have foreach loop where I'm trying to assign object taken from sql that contains id to my list model in which this item must be int.

```
 foreach (DataRow item in dtbProduct.Rows)
            {
                PaymentsList.Add(new Payments()
                {
                    PaymentID = item["p_ID"],
```

in this case I get syntax error

> cannot simplicitly convert objecto to int

But If I write

```
PaymentID = int.Parse(item["p_ID"].ToString()),
```

project runs but I receive runtime error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: What's the value of `item["p_ID"].ToString()`?

Comment: show us the value of  item["p_ID"].ToString()

Comment: What datatype is the p_ID? Since its probably used as a primary key in a database I assume this is an int64? In that case use int64.Parse()

Comment: have you Tried Convert.ToInt64(item["p_Id"]) ??

Comment: did that but syntax says cannot implicitly convert long to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is `Int` in sql then there may be some `null` values present which is giving error while converting. try checking for `null` values before converting to `int`

ex -

```
PaymentID = Convert.ToInt32( string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["p_ID"].ToString()) ? "0" : item["p_ID"].ToString()); // provided 0 if null
```

Have a try to this

Comment: this worked for me probably my select give me nulls and that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

instead of int.Parse you can use int.TryParse - read https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse

or if it's a long try long.TryParse

research mapping of data type in .net to sql server to establish what you need